# Set table row according to data while running

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

My sub report has a manually designed table. Sometimes I need to display 10 to 30 rows within a single cell, sometimes only 2 to 5 rows. I'd like the field to auto-resize based on the number of rows needed. How can I remove the unecessary white space?

Here is the space delegated for the FYR field:

[image]

Design section, details C through E:

[image]

Image displayed while running:

[[image][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBHcQ.png)

Comment: can you show design of report?

Comment: hi Mr.Siva sorry to trouble you, that I found answer for the above question.. Now I got another error..  I have designed  a crystal report with subreport-the subreport inside separate section.for ex.,I put subreport in Details d section... I never give any space between section c and section d. but while running, there is  4 to 5 line gap is appear on my report.. Is there any way to correct this..?

Comment: Actually without seeing design it is not possible to comment

Comment: i took screenshot of my report section but how to post here ? no option to add img?

Comment: you can attach a image there is option you can check

Comment: I cannot  find any option to add my screenshot Mr.Siva.. If I try to edit my question also ask 10 reputation to post more than 1 img..

Comment: finally I add my images- one is design other is output..sry i delete the text inside the report, as bcoz of this is company's one.

Comment: looks like in sub report there are some un used sections which are causing that space to appear.. check the sub report and if report headers and any sections above data section are not used supress and try the preview

Comment: actually, when I double check, I don't have any xtra detail section and in preview, I never see that gap.. preview looks good.. but while running only got that error

Comment: not extra detail may be group headers report headers which have no data but appearing in report

Comment: sry Mr.Siva.. I didn't get you.. becoz i never use any headers on that particular space.. If this is common, is there any other way to solve this..? bcoz, this is an urgent issue for me

Comment: Its not about usinf headers...those will be there automatically..show the design of sub report also when you double click the sub report in preview are you able to see space

Comment: In preview,there is no space for both main and sub report.. preview looks good..

Comment: That means there is no issue in report now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to tell from your screenshots, but I think you want to activate Can Grow for the selected fields.

Resize them all back to the size of one row, then right click the fields, open Field Explorer, and select Can Grow. You'll probably want to activate this for the subreport as well if it hasn't been. This way the fields should stretch and shrink vertically based on the amount of data they have to display.

Comment: Thanks ,As per your one I updated few columns only.. Also I makes the table line touches another section also make it grow itself, automatically.